# What are considered invalid fieldnames with arcpy Cursor classes?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, feature-class

Using this code, I get the following error.

```
infeature = r"C:\pathto\file.gdb\file" #location of feature class
fields = ["Name:", "Location", "Email Address", "Cell Phone Number:", 
          "Home Phone Number:"] #these are the fieldnames, not the aliases

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infeature, fields) as cursor1:
    for row in cursor1:
        print(row)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pathto\DuplicateFields_updated.py", line 18, in <module>
    for row in cursor1:
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT OBJECTID,Name:,Location,
Email Address,Cell Phone Number:,Home Phone Number: FROM backup_02232021_NEW]
```

In the [help docs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) and all the cursor-related questions here, I haven't found anything telling me how the fieldnames in a table should look. I have spaces and colons in mine. But, what if the fieldnames cannot be changed-- as in my case? I'm using a `SearchCursor` here, but my question goes for the other cursors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you were able to get those as the actual field names.  I would double check that they aren't field name aliases first.  There are definite restrictions on field names.  Details can be found at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-adding-and-deleting-fields.htm#GUID-8E190093-8F8F-4132-AF4F-B0C9220F76B3
Additionally, while it says it's for Spatial Analyst, a more detailed article about field name restrictions/best practices is at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/performing-analysis/field-names-in-spatial-analyst.htm and actually applies to dataset field names in ArcGIS more broadly than just Spatial Analyst.

As far as your specific field names, I've not seen ESRI products work with special characters or spaces in field names, though of course field name aliases can and regularly do look like what you listed as field names.

If you truly have those as your actual field names and can't change them, I would just prepare to have limits on what you can do with some ESRI tools/systems, as you're almost guaranteed to have more issues than just this.  Ideally, you probably should look at updating your database schema to use field names that follow best practices.

Comment: They are for certain actual field names. I didn't create the feature class, but I do know it was created using Survey123 Connect.

Comment: OK, it was staring me in the face, but I didn't see it. I was using the aliases afterall... my brain is mush.

Answer (score 1):

You've a colon in your `"Cell Phone Number:"` and `"Home Phone Number:"`  fields and that's throwing a invalid SQL statement.